# PyCrypto and AES: can i use a longer key than the block size (16byte)?

Tags: aes, key-size

I see that in many scripts are used keys of 16 characters for a block of 16 byte, but can I use key of 40 (for example)? And then why in some scripts with aes module the block size is set to 32 byte if aes can handle a fixed size block of 128 bit? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

> I see that in many scripts are used keys of 16 characters for a block of 16 byte, but can I use key of 40 (for example)?

No, AES uses a key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits. That's 16, 24 or 32 bytes.

> And then why in some scripts with aes module the block size is set to 32 byte if aes can handle a fixed size block of 128 bit? Is it correct?

No, that's not correct. It could however be that the module implements Rijndael instead of AES. AES is a subset of Rijndael, and Rijndael can have the block sizes 128, 160, 192, 224 and indeed 256 bits. So in that case the block size can be 256 bits.

---

Notes:

- not all implementations of Rijndael offer support for 160 and 224 bit block and key sizes (so many posts don't mention these block and key sizes);
- bytes are not characters, although the name of a byte in C/C++ is traditionally called a `char` as for ASCII each character is represented by exactly one byte - no conversion necessary;
- sometimes when characters are mentioned they actually contain hexadecimal digits; as you need two hexadecimal digits to *represent* one byte it may seem that 256 bits are used instead of the actual 128 bits.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but if aes supports keys of 256 bit can i use a longer key?

Comment: @HenryC you can use a key size of 16, 24, or 32 bytes

Comment: Not directly. The algorithm doesn't support it but 256 is plenty anyway. You can always use a KDF such as HKDF or PBKDF2 to compress larger input into 256 bits. Sometimes a hash or HMAC is used directly as a "poor man's" KDF (SHA-256 obviously makes a lot of sense in this case).